Pooling Participant Data to Resolve Limited Trials per Condition Issues
Problem: In an experimental task, there are 4 conditions with only 2 trials each, resulting in 8 observations per participant. Typically, we use Signal Detection Theory (SDT) to calculate descriptive statistics like the hit rate (H) or d prime(d’) and subsequently perform inferential statistics (e.g., repeated measures ANOVA of the 4 conditions on accuracy). However, the low number of trials per condition for each participant makes it impossible to calculate these statistics accurately. SDT standards require that for a given statistic (e.g. the hit rate H) to be considered valid and normally distributed, the number of trials per condition (N) must satisfy the inequalities NH > 5 and N(1-H) > 5. With only two trials per condition, these conditions are not met.
Possible Solutions: To overcome this, I am considering two potential solutions (the second seem to be a better version of the first one):

Grouping 200 participants into 25 groups of 8, combining their responses to form "macro-participants." Each macro-participant would then have 16 trials per condition, allowing for the valid computation of SDT descriptive statistics. These could then be analyzed conventionally, e.g., using ANOVA to compare performances across the 4 conditions.
Using a resampling method inspired by the Bootstrap to create macro-participants: Randomly sampling 10,000 groups of 8 participants (with replacement) to form 10,000 macro-participants for calculating SDT statistics, which would then be used for inferential statistics.

My Questions Are:

Is such a solution statistically valid?

If so, is the second approach (using Bootstrap) preferable?

Does this method have a specific name that I could use to find further references? (or related keywords like pooling, combining, merging, aggregate, …)

How can we address the dependency of data within each macro-participant ?


Thank you in advance for your help!
